# Realm.firstFirstAsync().asObservable() isn't consistently working with RxJava.switchIfEmpty

Tags: realm, rx-java

I am trying to create function which reads a object from realm and emit an empty observable if the object isn't found. The code below works to some degree because I can stop it with the debugger and see it hit the `Observable.empty()`:

```
fun readFromRealm(id: String): Observable<Player> {
    return realm.where(Player::class.java)
        .equalTo("id", id)
        .findFirstAsync()
        .asObservable<Player>()
        .filter { it.isLoaded }
        .flatMap {
            if (it.isValid)
                Observable.just(it)
            else
                Observable.empty()
        }
}
```

But when I try to use a `switchIfEmpty` on the Observable the code never emits `defaultPlayer` when it is not found in realm.

```
return readFromRealm(playerId)
        .take(1)
        .map{ // do something with emitted observable }
        .switchIfEmpty(Observable.just(defaultPlayer)) // use this if no player found
```

The strange thing is that if I update the original method to include a `first()` prior to the `flatMap` :

```
fun readFromRealm(id: String): Observable<Player> {
    return realm.where(Player::class.java)
        .equalTo("id", id)
        .findFirstAsync()
        .asObservable<Player>()
        .filter { it.isLoaded }
        .first() // add first 
        .flatMap {
            if (it.isValid)
                Observable.just(it)
            else
                Observable.empty()
        }
}
```

Everything starts working as expected, but I believe this version will kill auto updating because it will only capture the first result emitted after the filter.

I'm still trying to grok Realm and Rx so I'm probably doing something dumb.

EDIT: I have created a sample project which highlights the issue I'm seeing - https://github.com/donaldlittlepie/realm-async-issue

Comment: Yes. auto-update will continue to work, but your take(1), will kill the event from propagating further down the chain.

Comment: Try using `findAllAsync()` and somehow use `map()` to do `if(count > 0) { return results.get(0); } else { return null; }` but I don't know how to write that in Rx so this is a comment instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reasons I don't totally understand. If you move `take(1)` just above the 
`flatMap` and below the `filter` it should work correctly:

```
   realm.where(Dog.class)
            .equalTo("id", 0L)
            .findFirstAsync()
            .asObservable()
            .cast(Dog.class)
            .filter(new Func1<RealmObject, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(RealmObject realmObject) {
                    return realmObject.isLoaded();
                }
            })
            .take(1) // <== here
            .flatMap(new Func1<Dog, Observable<Dog>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Dog> call(Dog realmObject) {
                    if (realmObject.isValid()) {
                        return Observable.just(realmObject);
                    } else {
                        return Observable.empty();
                    }
                }
            })
            .map(new Func1<Dog, Dog>() {
                @Override
                public Dog call(Dog dog) {
                    dog.setName("mapped " + dog.getName());
                    return dog;
                }
            })
            .switchIfEmpty(Observable.just(createDefaultDog()))
            .subscribe(new Action1<Dog>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Dog dog) {
                    textView.setText(dog.getName());
                }
            }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                    textView.setText(throwable.toString());

                }
            });
```

My best guess is that before, `flatMap` was called repeatedly, returning `Observable.empty()` multiple times. Perhaps that effects the Observable chain in some unexpected way.

Comment: I agree this sample works.  I actually tried as well to take realm out of the picture to make sure everything lined up.

Comment: I created a sample project which highlights the issue I'm seeing https://github.com/donaldlittlepie/realm-async-issue. In `MainActivity.java` I have two text views which should be updated based on my realm result. The method `findEmptyInRealm` never gets to the subscription.

Comment: Thanks for the project. I updated my answer with my findings

Comment: EDIT: Ups, just noticed you discovered the same using `first()`